# Audio stopped in avi file using gstreamer

Tags: file, audio, gstreamer, avi

I tried to play avi file using gst-launch utility.
when i played seperatly audio and video both  are working fine.if i tried run both using

gst-launch  filesrc location=sample.avi ! avidemux name=demux demux.audio_00 ! adpcmdec !  alsasink demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4_msv2  ! xvimagesink

audio stoping.
gst-launch playbin uri=file:///sample.avi
with playbin working fine.

Can some body tell the reason  and do i need to set any other arguments in pipeline.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Break it down even farther: Does this play audio? "gst-launch filesrc location=sample.avi ! avidemux ! adpcmdec ! alsasink" Does this play video? "gst-launch filesrc location=sample.avi ! avidemux ! ffdec_mpeg4_msv2 ! xvimagesink"

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the queue on the audio side:
gst-launch filesrc location=sample.avi ! avidemux name=demux demux.audio_00 ! queue ! adpcmdec ! alsasink demux.video_00 ! queue ! ffdec_mpeg4_msv2 ! xvimagesink